# Куда делось дисковое пространство?

Tags: ubuntu, disk

В Ubuntu 18.04 под рутом делаю df -h, получаю:

```
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/vda1                             40G   36G  2,4G  94% /
...
```

, то есть использовано 36 Gb.

Далее делаю du -sm *| sort -nr, получаю:

```
du: cannot access 'proc/1557/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
22892   home
3329    var
1735    lib
1004    usr
243 boot
176 backup
21  run
15  tmp
9   bin
8   etc
6   sbin
1   srv
1   root
1   opt
1   mnt
1   media
1   lost+found
1   lib64
0   vmlinuz.old
...
```

То есть занято 22892+3329+1735+1004+243+176+21+15+9+8+6+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=29445 Mb

Куда делись 36-29 = 7 Gb?

Озадачиваюсь вопросом в связи с тем, что каждые сутки бесследно исчезают по несколько десятков мегабайт.

Comment: Не совсем по теме вопроса, но попробуйте `ncdu`, у него относительно дружелюбный интерфейс

Comment: Но и для `du` рекомендую использовать опцию `-x` / `--one-file-system` и вместо звёздочки указывать путь к корню `/`

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
df --block-size=M --output=used,target /dev/vda1

du --block-size=M --summarize --one-file-system /
```

Comment: Вывод этих двух команд:
root@stg:/home/support# df --block-size=M --output=used,target /dev/vda1
  Used Mounted on
36238M /

root@stg:/home/support# du --block-size=M --summarize --one-file-system /
29418M /
то есть на 7Gb не сходится. Задача в том, чтобы определить в каких папках/разделах эти 7 Gb.

Comment: @vito, интересно, а что показывает команда `lsblk -do "NAME,TRAN,PTTYPE,FSTYPE,SIZE,FSSIZE,FSAVAIL,FSUSED,FSROOTS" /dev/vda1`

Comment: lsblk: unknown column: PTTYPE,FSTYPE,SIZE,FSSIZE,FSAVAIL,FSUSED,FSROOTS